# Obfusticating License key which is hardcoded

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

Im using some 3rd party Dll's in my code which require a license key to work.

The license key needs to be passed into the methods when called or they don't work.

However I have written my code in C# which means this license key can be retrieved by decompiling my code.

Is there any way for this license string to be prevented from being decompiled?

Comment: Well, you need to obfusticate it! The next question is *how* do you want to do that? What have you already tried?

Comment: Assuming that the license key is a string stored as plaintext it can be trivially retrieved no matter what the language is. Unmanaged code would let you store it encrypted and make reverse-engineering the decryption harder, but without encryption that's moot.

Comment: Yes its being stored in Plain Text. I have not tried anything yet because im not sure whats possible. Any encryption I do is kinda pointless as some "password" key needs to be stored in the code to decrypt it!!

Comment: Additionally, even with encryption and unmanaged code it could be pretty easy to get your license key: I create a DLL with a method that mirrors one of your 3rd party DLLs. I overwrite the 3rd party DLL with my code and run your program. I don't have to do any hard work: your code will decrypt the license key and call my function with it -- you have handed me the key on a platter.

Comment: Ya that's my problem. I cant think of any decent way to protect the license. Probably not possible?!

Comment: Of course. That's why all games and applications can be (and are) cracked. You can only make it harder for the cracker, it's impossible to have 100% protection.

Comment: If you are licensed to "redistribute" this component, then I am not sure why it matters if someone gets your key. Does it?  They would be in violation, not you.

Comment: Yes im licensed to redistribute. I suppose it doesn't really matter but id rather that my license doesn't get widly used.

Comment: The problem here is the method choosen by the 3rd party library builder. If they want you to pass the license in clear text, then you pass it in clear text. I think that you can't be accounted of any kind of violation if they choose this way

Comment: @Jon - your proposal to overwrite the 3rd party DLL is only possible if is not signed...

Comment: @Vadim: That was just an idea, and obviously there are ways to put up resistance. Signed DLLs are good, but my main point is that it all depends and there is no end-all solution.

Comment: @Jon - I totally agree with you. Just wanted to point out that this specific example is not very conclusive.

Answer (score 3):

(adding as an answer because the message is too long for a comment)

There is no way to completely block access to this string, you can only make it harder. Even if you encrypt it, your program will need the ability to decrypt it, which means that anyone skilled enough can access and reuse the decryption mechanism to get the key in clear format. Or they could even simply read the decrypted key from memory.

Answer (score 3):

You could store the License key in app.config and then encrypt it:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18209/Encrypting-the-app-config-File-for-Windows-Forms-A

That probably gets you the most bang for the least buck.

Comment: And how this would avoid the simple crack scheme outlined by @jon in its comment above?

Comment: I didn't say it would.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't worry too much about it**. If your application has access to the key then anyone with access to the binaries and enough time can get that key.

**Keep in mind is not your licensing scheme which is at risk**, is the licensing scheme of the 3rd party one and thus you have to rely on the applicable laws. If someone decompiles your application and gets access to the key they're breaking the law and it's something you can't prevent.

Your app has the legal rights to use that third library, breaking it has to be handled by law, not by protection, and it's a violation by the terms of the 3rd party licensing scheme. You can go into a certain length to protect it but in the end the responsibility is not yours as there's no way the data can be completely protected (your app needs to know that key and so, at some point, that key will be available in plain text for anyone with access to the code to pick on it). That is true even if the app was entirely written in assembly language.

Answer (score 1):

Add strong verbiage to your license agreement against de-compiling and/or using any licenses that you have acquired in their own software.  Require users to electronically accept these terms.  Record the timestamp and IP address of each user that accepts these terms on your own server.

If you wanted to add some basic obfuscation in addition to this, that it ok too.  But the main point is that as a licensed re-distributor of this component, you are making a concerted effort to prevent others from using your key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something simple without encryption, to stop a plain-text view of the license:
Store the string in your code and do some replacing before using it, for example:

```
string LicenseCode = "croftycot";

// Use license code
CallUsingLicense(LicenseCode.Replace("o","a")); // Change to real code: craftycat
```

You can get more complicated if you need with a regular expressions, mixing a few strings together etc.

Comment: Why the downvote? I know it's a cheap solution, but so is passing a plain text license key ... seemed to fit quite well.

Comment: I was looking for a way to obfuscate my hardcoded keys and found this. It gave me a basic idea of how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: *YOU* cannot encrypt a string well there are ways but if as said by @Xavier Poinas you can only make it harder so it's always beneficial/better to make it harder to get the string then just leave it unencrypted because if it's encrypted to the point where it's a real hassle to get the code, it could leave them to just forget about it and move on. This is a valid answer... Voted +1.